# Basic number theory question, proving something is an integer.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a$ and $n$ be two non-zero natural numbers that are relatively prime. 
Show that there exists $b \in \mathbb Z$ such that $ab \equiv 1\pmod n$.

So $(a,n)=1$ and we know there exists $\alpha, b \in \mathbb Z$ such that $$\alpha a + b n =1$$ and $$b=\frac{1-\alpha a}{n}$$

Where did I go wrong this problem?

Comment: You wrote "$b\in\mathbb{Z}$".  So $b$ is an integer by assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The puzzlement is due to a non-optimal choice of letters.

There exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $ax+ny=1$. Taking $b=x$, we get that $ab\equiv 1\pmod{n}$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* $am \equiv ak \pmod n$ implies $m \equiv k \pmod n$.